# How do I find the odds ratio using the output of a loglinear model?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, odds-ratio, log-linear

This was a homework problem from Agresti (7.2) that I didn't get, even after looking at my class' solutions. Help?

So we are given the output of a loglinear regression ($λ_{ij}^{XY}$). The output is:

```
 parameter                  |  df  |  Estimate
 gender*belief Female  Yes  |   1  |  0.1368
 gender*belief Female  No   |   0  |  0 
 gender*belief Male    Yes  |   0  |  0
 gender*belief Male    No   |   0  |  0
```

From this, I need to calculate the odds ratio. What I know is that:

$\log(θ) = λ_{11}^{XY} + λ_{22}^{XY} - λ_{12}^{XY} - λ_{12}^{XY}$

From this, I did:

> $\log(θ) = 0.1368 + 0 - 0 - 0$
> $θ = \exp(0.1368) = \mathbf{1.147}$

That ended up wrong. The answer from my class' solution set is:

> $\log(\mu) = λ + λ_{1}^{X}I_\text{female} + λ_{2}^{Y}I_\text{male} + 0.1368I_{(\text{female, belief})}$
> $θ = \exp(-0.1368) = \mathbf{0.8721}$
>
> interpretation: after allowing for interaction between gender and belief, the odds of belief in the afterlife in males is 87% of that of females

I've spent nearly an hour and I still don't get why. My questions are

1. How do you know which coefficient in the output corresponds to which lambda? (e.g. what is 11? 12? 22? 21?)
2. Why did the solutions take the antilog of a negative beta?

EDIT: the book is Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis 2nd ed

Comment: I've attempted to clarify your mathematics, but if I've misunderstood the intent (your mathematics was ambiguous), it may be necessary to edit further. If you don't see how to do that, type @Glen_b in a comment (which will notify me) and explain the problem and I (or possibly someone else) will try to help you fix it

Comment: Please also give a full reference for Agresti. He wrote more than one book!